# removing speciacl characters from teradata coloumn

Tags: sql, special-characters, teradata

how to remove special characters from Teradata columns.
I am having columns values other than characters A-Z and numbers 1-9, how to remove theses column values as we don't know the exact special character. Can any one share the command for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression, `'[^0-9a-z]'` to find characters which don't match a list of characters:

```
regexp_replace(col, '[^0-9a-z]', '', 1, 0, 'i')
```

Comment: Thanks , i am facing issue for characters like this  ' ÉCLAIR', the  É is not getting removed the regex_replace.

Comment: @user4836066: What's your Teradata release? This works fine for me.

Comment: Tearadat 14.00 version